# JS: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, list, arguments

I have this error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

function:

```
function toTimestampArti(strDate, dk) 
{
        var birdk = 60000;
        var artidk = dk * birdk;
        var datum = Date.parse(strDate);
        var timeoff = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000 * -1;
        var time = datum + timeoff + artidk;
        return time;
}
```

run code:

```
toTimestampArti(strDate:06.01.2018 08:30:00, dk:10)
```

Comment: You don't call JavaScript functions with colons. Also strings have to be delimited with quotes. Looks like you are confusing JavaScript with another language. You are supposed to call this like `toTimestampArti('06.01.2018 08:30:00', 10)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call with values, without giving the variable, because the order defines the argument.

For the date, you need to take a string.

```
toTimestampArti('06.01.2018 08:30:00', 10)
```